# When does $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n,m}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n,n}$, and an example when this is true

Tags: real-analysis

I've seen example that uses the trick $\int_{0}^\infty f(x)\, dx =\int_{0}^n f_n(x) \, dx$, where $f_n$ converges to $f$. But I know this is not always true. So there is an attempt for justification for a certian example

Showing that as $n$ goes to infinity

$$\int_0^n \Big(1-\frac{x}{n}\Big)^n x^s \,dx= \int_0^\infty x^s e^{-x}\, dx$$
Let :
$$K=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Big|\int_0^n x^s \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \, dx -\int_0^\infty x^s \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\, dx\Big|$$
Show that $K=0 $

Proof: Here we omit the limit notation and assume $n$ goes to infinity
$$K=\Big |\int_n^\infty x^s \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\, dx\Big|$$
Let $x=un$ $\Rightarrow dx=n \, du$, which the integral becomes:
$$K=\Big| \int_1^{\infty} (1-u)^n (un)^s n\, du\Big|\,\, ,( 1/u=t)$$
$$=\Big|\int_0^1 \left( 1-\frac{1}{t}\right)^n\frac{n^{s+1}}{t^{s+2}}\, dt\Big|=n^{s+1}\int_0^1 (1-t)^n t^{-(s+n+2)}\, dt$$
$$=n^{s+1} \frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(-n-s-1)}{\Gamma(-s)}=$$
$$=-n^{s+1} \frac{\pi \Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(-s)\Gamma(n+s+2)\sin(\pi(n+s+1))}$$
$$=-\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(-s)\sin(\pi(s+n+1))}\cdot\frac{n^{s+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+s+1)}\frac{1}{n+s+2}$$
If $s$ is not an integer, this equals to
$$\mathrm{Bounded}\cdot 1\cdot \frac{1}{n+s+2}$$
Which converges to zero.

I have two questions

$(1) $ is my proof correct

$(2)$ (and this is my sought one, so please answer this.) Is there a general theorem that gives conditions to $(a_{n,m})$ and states $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n,n} $ converges to the same value as $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n,m}?$

Thank you.

Comment: Please focus on one question per post.

Comment: I'm sorry there was a typo

Comment: Why? I've seen countless post asking questions multiple questions (since we can't post multiple questions at the same time). And everyone seems fine about it.

Comment: Because your 2 questions are very distinct and appeal 2 distinct answers, though you seem to demand an answer to both at the same time. Why cannot you edit 2 separate posts, one after another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "[Moore-Osgood Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit)" states that if the sequence $a_{n,m}$ has the properties that $(i)$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,m}$ converges uniformly in $m$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{n,m}$ converges, then the iterated limits $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to \infty}a_{n,m}$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n,m}$ exist and are equal to the double limit $\lim_{(n,m)\to(\infty,\infty)}a_{n,m}$.

Note that the conditions are sufficient only and not necessary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

About your first question:
$$\forall n\ge-s-1,\quad K=\frac1{n^n}\int_n^\infty x^s \left(x-n\right)^n\, dx=\frac1{n^n}(+\infty)=+\infty$$